# what is the problem of grounding a 1 ohm resistor to a power supply?

Tags: power-supply, resistors

(Vcc)-(load)-(1 ohm 5 watt)-(gnd)

I am making a dc-dc boost power supply circuit, and I need a shunt resistor to measure the current. is there a con or problem in this approach of using a 1 ohm resistor?

Comment: Nothing, if power dissipation in shunt is not exceeding above 5W.

Answer (score 3):

The higher the current is the higher the load ground will be above supply ground. This may be acceptable in isolated systems, but in systems that connect with other devices there can be a real problem if current goes above a few hundred milliamps.

Also, the higher the current is the lower the supply voltage will be. This means that your system will brownout itself easily if it draws too much current.

The way around both of these is to use a *much* lower resistance, 50mohm or less, and an in amp shunt amplifier (e.g. [INA213](http://www.ti.com/product/ina213)) to raise the difference to measurable levels. Integrated solutions (e.g. [INA250](http://www.ti.com/product/ina250)) also exist.

Comment: Can't one just move the sense resistor to the high-side of the load (for the 1st problem, i.e. to avoid a floating ground)? Doing that does nothing to address a possible brownout, of course... but is much cheaper than INAs.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff: That doesn't eliminate the first problem, it merely changes its behavior. Instead of the ground you now have the problem of different positive supply voltages, which can cause external signals to stress high protection diodes instead of low ones.

Comment: Still, I haven't seen much in the way of INAs in DC/DC converters... My guess is that because they usually implement a rather non-precise current limiting method instead.

Comment: DC/DC converters can get away with a low-side ground-referenced op amp for shunt measurement since there's no way to connect the "true" internal ground to any external system.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the issue is, what is the low side of the shunt connected to? Analyze your circuit carefully to make sure it is not connected to Earth GND (for example, is the low side of your input power connected to Earth GND, or does it float?).

A user of your supply might connect the output side to earth ground either on purpose, or accidentally by connecting it to equipment that is earth grounded. Think about it carefully. This would effectively short out your shunt and provide an undesirable path for current through whatever cabling is making the earth ground connection. If you are sure your resistor low side is isolated from the external world, then it is OK. But these problems can actually be pretty hard to figure out. For some reason, GND is confusing.

If you have the option of putting the current sensing on the high side, it is much better.